# ITunes volume noticeably lower than browser volume

Tags: itunes, audio

Can anyone think of a reason why (and a possible solution) the volume on my ITunes player is lower than other apps (like for example playing videos on youtube or music in grooveshark)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you're not aware that there is a volume slider on the iTunes window?

[image]

Also, Are you using an Equalizer? (Window -> Equalizer)

Change the preamp setting if you feel it is too quiet.

[image]

Comment: Please. I'm not an idiot

Comment: Hey, some people may just say "doh, I hadn't even noticed!"

Comment: @Pablo I added to my answer with another method to affect the volume in iTunes.